# In Swift, Detect Tap in Portion of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Hopefully, this is an easy question for iOS/Swift developers.  I have a UITableViewCell with text on the left and an image on the right.  If the user taps on the row, I do something and that is working just fine.  However, if the user taps on the image, I need to do something else.  I took a look at [Detect Tap on UIImageView within UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761981/detect-tap-on-uiimageview-within-uitableviewcell) but I don't translate Objective-C to Swift very well.

My assumption is that I need to do something like this in my subclassed UITableViewCell:

```
@IBOutlet var handsfreeImage: UIImageView!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let handsfreeTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: handsfreeImage, action:Selector("handsfreeTap:"))
}

func handsfreeTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    println("The handsfree image was tapped")
}
```

However, this is not working.  Thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't just use a `UIButton` instead of `UIImageView`?

Comment: I tried both and could neither to work using UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: You don't need a tap gesture if you're using a button; just attach a target+action.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the `UITapGestureRecognizer` correctly.

The `target` should be the class that implements the handler method.

So it should be

`let handsfreeTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handsfreeTap:"))`

Then you need to actually add the gesture recognizer to the view.

```
handsfreeImage.addGestureRecognizer(handsfreeTap)
```

That should all work. It might not still behave exactly the way you want because it will be missing some functionality such as long holds, and tap highlights. If these are things you care about, I would recommend simply using a `UIButton` with an `image` background instead of using a `UIImageView` because it handles all of that internally without you having to deal with it.

Comment: Nope, it still picks up the row tap rather than the specific image tap within the row.

Comment: I also tried the button, in each case the row tap is picked up and the touch on the image/button is ignored.

Comment: You may also need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to true.

Comment: For the UIImageView, I did and when I switched to a UIButton, it is by default.

Answer (score 2):

You created the recognizer, but you still need to add it to the view.  So

```
whateverYourImageViewIs.addGestureRecognizer(handsfreeTap)
```

Comment: I did after Dima reminded of that fact but I still could not get it to work. That is when I went with the approach I documented in my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

So, I never was able to get the UITapGestureRecognizer approach to work (which is sad because I thought it was an elegant solution).  So, I ended up using the delegate approach:

```
protocol HandsFreeTapCellDelegate {
    func handsFreeTap(handsFreeButton: VehicleTableViewCell)
}

class VehicleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate : HandsFreeTapCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func handsFreeTap(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.handsFreeTap(self)
    }
}

class FooViewController: UIViewController, HandsFreeTapCellDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func handsFreeTap(handsFreeButton: VehicleTableViewCell) {
        println("handsfreeButton was tapped, the row is: \(handsFreeButton.tag)")
    }
}
```